# how to validate div element in angular UI bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I make view from array of object into view .But My problem is that I take div element inside the li and ui .Now I want to validate element like "number", "url","email".I need to validate element on **blur** and **keyup**.Some elements may be required some not .I need to show this using "*".I know how to validate using form when I take form I used

```
 <span ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required" class="help-inline">
```

But now i have div element inside li .how I will validate .?
http://plnkr.co/edit/we1QHuDuCOOR4tDAk6yv?p=preview

```
 function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.outputs = {};
    $scope.inputs = [{
        type: "email",
        name: "email",
        required:true
    }, {
        type: "text",
        name: "name",
    }, {
        type: "number",
        name: "phonenumber",
    }, {
        type: "checkbox",
        name: "whant to check",
    },
    {
        type: "url",
        name: "server Url",
    }];

}
```

or is there any way to insert all element in form ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular Form Validation.

When i was searching about this, i found out [this tutorial](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation). It has helped me alot.

Try your self.

Comment: this form validation..he want to add in in div validation